# how to save the state of my checkbox list before binding it again on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I'm new with asp and c#. I have a checkbox list bound to a data source. How do I save the state of my checkbox list so that the checkboxes will be retained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it stays bound to the same data source, then you would need to ensure that the values are persisted to the data source so that it is refreshed correctly on re-bind.

Other more painful options would be to persist that information elsewhere, and try to programatically reapply the values based on that, after the re-bind has finished.